# Many colliders on animated object makes significant performance impact

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I have a problem with colliders on enemies. Of course, colliders are used as hitboxes/hurtboxes you can name it how you want. Each body part like a hand, arm, forearm, foot, etc has a Capsule Collider. We found that we can't really have more than 30 enemies on mobile devices because when the enemy is animated (root motion animations like walking, running etc) we have a heavy load of physics. We tested that, enemies without animations are good, only with animation but without scripts, etc.

Can somebody tell me what we are doing wrong? How do you guys handle stuff like hitboxes on enemies in Unity?

EDIT: This is 3D game, we have one Rigidbody for each enemy

Comment: Have you tried [Ragdoll](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/creating-ragdolls-2019)? Not sure but it might be more performant than individual colliders

Comment: Is this a 3D game ? or 2.5D or 2D

Comment: Yeah this is 3D game

Comment: Why do you need multiple hit boxes? As you can find a point where a hit was on a collider could you not reduce to one!?

Comment: @BugFinder how can I create one collider which will be precise on enemy character model? It's not a cube it's humanoid model

Comment: Hey there. If it is lagging during animations, there is probably so many keys in your animation. Try keyframe reduction in unity. Also if your shadows rendering real-time, it will take all the performance. It could lag because of colliders if your colliders are not low poly. You could use bunch of cube colliders to make hitboxes. 14 cube colliders I think will be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most games have quite simple hitboxes for Physics collision (like a cylinder/capsule) and more complex hitboxes used solely for raycasting/combat mechanics, separated from the rigidbody (and ignored by physics).

This means that the physics engine is never doing too much work, and the raycasting/combat hitboxes are only tested when they need to be.

[image: Mesh Collider options]

[`Mesh Collider` docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MeshCollider.html) explains:

> **Is Trigger**: Enable this checkbox to make Unity use this Collider for triggering events, and the physics engine
> ignore it.

Comment: Essentially, the fact that all your physics hitboxes are constantly being animated is slowing down the physics engine with unnecessary updates

Comment: "Mesh colliders are extremely slow to update, so you wouldn't want them to animate even if it was possible. Instead use a primitive collider or compound primitive collider and attach it to the appropriate bone;"
Isn't that true? Can I use mesh collider on animated character?

Comment: Yes, that is true to an extent. Mesh colliders are much more complex shapes, so collision detection is more complicated (therefore slower). Using a primitive shape such as a box collider would improve performance, and like I said, you can have distinct colliders for physics collision and hitbox collision, so you can maintain a compromise in collision quality depending on your needs.

Comment: You can always combine many box colliders to compose your complete hitboxes, if you look online for "hitboxes" you almost always see they use combinations of box colliders (for performance over mesh colliders)

Comment: As I said, we have many capsule colliders on characters. The problem is we can't change them to triggers because we have IK and melee weapon combat, but just for firearms, it would work...

Comment: That's tricky then. One thing you could try, is to separate colliders onto [different physics layers](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html), and see if the engine can optimize the collision calculations by skipping unnecessary ones (e.g most character colliders probably don't need to interact with the scene collision)

Comment: We did it. I thought maybe we missed something or there is a better way, but probably we have to optimize other things that use physics. Everything you wrote is correct and even it is not that magic solution that I searched for, I think for many can be useful so thanks!